# Angular Attribute Directives and Valid Accessible HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, accessibility, angular2-directives

I've recently begun work on a project that requires the application to be as accessible as possible and have come across an issue where the HTML is being marked as invalid by https://validator.w3.org. I haven't seen anything in the Angular documentation that mentions HTML Validity (probably for good reason), but I'm coming under a lot of pressure to get it passing with flying colours.

Back in the day when I was creating relatively static websites, all custom HTML attributes would be prefixed with the `data` flag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes, to ensure that any Validator would figuratively ignore them, but I don't feel like this is the correct way to do this within angular.

For a simple example, below I have an unordered list that outputs some errors, with a link to the corresponding error on the page.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let error of errors">
    <a
      routerLink="."
      fragment="{{ transformName(error.name) }}-error"
      queryParamsHandling="merge"
    >
      {{ error.message }}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Angular then outputs the following HTML.

```
<ul>
  <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
  }-->
  <li>
    <a
      queryparamshandling="merge"
      routerlink="."
      ng-reflect-fragment="username-error"
      ng-reflect-query-params-handling="merge"
      ng-reflect-router-link="."
      href="/login#username-error"
    >
      Please enter your username.
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a
      queryparamshandling="merge"
      routerlink="."
      ng-reflect-fragment="password-error"
      ng-reflect-query-params-handling="merge"
      ng-reflect-router-link="."
      href="/login#password-error"
    >
      Please enter your password.
    </a>
  </li>
  <!--bindings={}--><!--bindings={}-->
</ul>
```

This is obviously not valid HTML as the following properties are not valid attributes for the `a` element

- queryparamshandling
- routerlink
- ng-reflect-fragment
- ng-reflect-query-params-handling
- ng-reflect-router-link

If I add the `data` some of the Angular attribute directives still work, but others like `routerLink` then complain that `fragment` isn't a property.

Or do I bind every attribute directive like so

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let error of errors">
    <a
      [routerLink]="['.']"
      [fragment]="transformName(error.name)+'-error"
      [queryParamsHandling]="'merge'"
    >
      {{ error.message }}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Which then outputs cleaner HTML, but I'm worried that Angular might be missing something

```
<ul>
  <!---->
  <li><a href="/login#username-error"> Please enter your username. </a></li>
  <li><a href="/login#password-error"> Please enter your password. </a></li>
  <!----><!---->
</ul>
```

---

So I guess my question is:

Has anyone had to work with Angular in this sort of fashion, and are there any tips or documentation on how to produce valid HTML with Angular?

Sorry if this question was a little long!
Thanks in advance for taking the time to read it.